# Change data with no name in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element in my html which has data attribute like this:

```
<object id="main_stream" data="Value1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

Now I want to change the value of data using jquery to value2. But since it doesn't have any name I don't know how to do it. I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
$("#main_stream").data("",stream_link);
```

My second question is that this is a video player. Even once the value is changed how can I refresh it so it shows the new video?

Comment: Use `attr()`. `$("#main_stream").attr('data', ---);`

Comment: @Tushar wow I can't believe I forgot about attr. thanks it solved both questions

Comment: why there is two **id** in html element?

Comment: @KrupeshKotecha it was my typo thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function

```
$("#main_stream").attr("data", stream_link);
```

To refresh the video it will depend on what sort of player you are using. This should really be a seperate question but I would recommend taking a look at what can be done with HTML5: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Answer (score 1):

$("#main_stream").attr("data","value2");

depending on the video player you are using or embedding, there may be an api call you can make to the website that changes the video (Twitch and Youtube both have this), or if there is no such option you can simply delete the html element with the video (iframe, ect.) and add it back in with the correct URI. Deleting is the less desirable option of course because it entails reloading of the player.